# Wpf Application Crash on Client Machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, app.xaml

My application is an "Offline System"
We can download appointments in that application and can use those application in offline mode, and that data can be upload when we have internet available.
But my Issue is: On client system our application crash with or without internet and i do not understand the reason. Below is the image or error message.
 That message is from Login screen when user try to login in offline mode[image]

Any Suggestions please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is there right in front of you, most possibly when trying to login (whatever your code behind is) there is a network error that is not handled and thus the exception crashing the exception.

Comment: Also it would be great if you share the code behind, along with your problem which would be a great help for anyone trying to help you. Do have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help you understand how you can imrpove the way you put a question here.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates some kind of network connectivity issue. The best way to find out why, is to check the inner exception as mentioned in your stacktrace:

> See inner exception, if present, for more details

Assuing you have this kind of code:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var message = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
```

Re-write doing something like this:

```
try {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var message = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
}
```

Since it is expected to have these exceptions while offline, when you get it, you should wait and retry later on.

Alternatively, you can use the network availability change to spin up your upload function

```
NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged 
    += new NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged);
```

Comment: I am handling catch like this:  catch (Exception ex)
            {            
                string exp = "InnerException: " + ex.InnerException + ", Message: " + ex.Message + ", StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace;
                MessageBox.Show(exp);
            }

Comment: This is a DNS problem. You can't resolve the hostname to the proper ip, which means that you are either not connected to the internet or that the hostname is wrong. Try to manually add the hostname with an ip in your hosts file and see what's happening. Allso try from tour console `nslookup https://<hostname>`